# Bootstrap a link does not vertically center, but button does

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, vertical-alignment

I want to have a `<a></a>` in which the text vertically centers, like the buttons does. Can someone explain why the `<button></button>` is vertically centered and not the link?

Line height does not work(see below)

```css
.btn {
  height: 70px;
}

.line-height-example {
   line-height: 30px;
   min-height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Not centered</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Centered</button>
<br><br>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary line-height-example">Line height</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary line-height-example">Line height example</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.btn {
  height: 70px;
}

.line-height-example {
   line-height: 30px;
   min-height: 45px;
}
a {
 display:inline-flex !important;
 align-items:center !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Not centered</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Centered</button>
<br><br>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary line-height-example">Line height</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary line-height-example">Line height example</a>
  </div>
</div>
```